# Equivalente de "Date.now()" do JavaScript em C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, datetime, timestamp

[Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) fala como obter milissegundos usando `Date.now();`, que retorna algo como `1533144170651`.

Segue documentação dele:

> O método `now()` retorna os milisegundos decorridos desde 1 de janeiro
> de 1970 00:00:00 UTC até agora como um Number.

Como eu posso fazer isso em C# (desde 1 de janeiro de 1970 00:00:00)? Tentei desta forma:

```
int mil = DateTime.Now.Millisecond; // Retorna 898
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Em versões recentes pode usar assim:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HpPTOO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rHcfQ9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Timestamp.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_ToUnixTimeMilliseconds).

Quase sempre usa-se `UtcNow`. Geralmente você está representando o ponto no tempo, portanto não pode ter variação não importa onde seja usado. Você usa o horário universal no sistema e o horário local como apresentação apenas. Só usa a hora local no sistema se precisa dela como uma marcação, algo puramente descritivo e não como um ponto no tempo. Chega ao ponto que se precisa usar isso é melhor até usar uma *string* com o horário já que não é um ponto no tempo.

O crédito da forma direta vai para o Guilherme Nascimento, eu não me lembrava que tinha como acessar o relógio da máquina direto por essa classe, ainda usava uma forma antiga.

Comment: Esse código retorna desde desde 1 de janeiro de 1970 00:00:00 ?

Comment: Sim, igual ao JS. O que pode ser verificado nos links que eu postei.

Comment: Nossa não sabia disso: `ToUnixTimeSeconds()`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda me enganei, `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` já faz todo o ajuste, li bastante coisas, e tanto usando .utcNow quanto .now o resultado será o mesmo para `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds`, pois provavelmente a classe internamente já sabe a timezone que o servidor opera, então desconsiderem o meu outro comentário.

Answer (score 5):

A propriedade [Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) do C# traz a data e hora atual, diferente do Now do JS.

A propriedade **Millisecond** retorna um inteiro equivalente aos milisegundos do momento em que Now foi avaliado. Fica mais claro com o exemplo abaixo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Data com millisegundos: {0:MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss.fff}, {1}", 
                  DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

Para que criar o mesmo comportamento no C# você deve fazer assim:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
        double x = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks).TotalMilliseconds;
        double y =((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        Console.WriteLine("Calculo com Ticks {0}",x);
        Console.WriteLine("Calculo com UtcNow {0}",y);      

    }
}
```

Note que o método com Ticks tem uma resolução ligeiramente maior que o método com o UTCNow.

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ydfeZN)

Comment: DateTime.Now, retorna data e hora.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Obrigado... corrigido.

Answer (score 4):

Não seria mais simples usar diretamente o `.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` no [`DateTimeOffset.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.now(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Assim:

- Milissegundos:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine( DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );
  ```
- Segundos (se interessar a alguém):

  ```
  Console.WriteLine( DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() );
  ```

Note que o unico problema que talvez enfrente com o método `.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` seria a questão de usar isto em uma versão inferior a *4.6* do *.NET Framework* (o que seria problema de todas respostas feitas aqui até agora).

Ao invés de fazer o *cast* do `DateTime.UtcNow` para `DateTimeOffset`

> Nota:
>
> Usar `DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` ou  `DateTime.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` parecem ter o mesmo efeito para `.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` pois provavelmente a classe sabe o horario e zona horaria e deve compensar sozinho isto no retorno do método.

---

Estrutura DateTimeOffset: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatheusMiranda então tá otimo, eu não disse até 4.6, eu disse inferior a 4.6, ou seja 4.6 em diante funciona, 4.5 e anteriores não, inclusive todas respostas usaram `ToUnixTimeSeconds`, então você deveria entender que todas tem o tal problema com versões antigas do net framework, mas acho que agora já ficou claro, de qualquer forma eu só quis responder com algo mais simples e sem precisar fazer *cast*. Pode usar ai que vai ver que funciona.

Comment: Comentei errado

Comment: Aqui é versão 4.7.2 :)

Comment: Cara a sua resposta está melhor que Maniero e menos código.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda obrigado!

Comment: Deixa te perguntar, quando a pergunta foi aceita, não se pode mais alterar ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda pode sim, basta clicar no botão com o desenho assim ✅ que fica ao lado de todas resposta (cada resposta tem um), ao fazer isso vc troca a resposta que considera como correta.

Comment: As duas estão corretas, porem a sua está melhor que dele. É necessário ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda eu realmente prefiro não opinar muito pq é a sua decisão pessoal do que resolveu e do que vc acha melhor, se considera esta melhor pode fazer a troca a vontade e se você se arrepender e quiser voltar atrás poderá trocar novamente ;)

Comment: Até quando posso trocar resposta como aceita ? Não tem limite ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda acho que a qualquer momento que desejar, só não pode desfazer o aceito depois de algum tempo, só não lembro "o limite"

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser um valor similar ao `javascript` pode calcular a diferença entre a data/hora atual e 01/01/1970:

```
var d = Math.Floor((DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()- new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Veja aqui funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7G2Wpx

Comment: Quase Ricardo, está retornando como double: `1533146367967.885`.

Comment: Sim verdade, usei um `Floor` para resolver isso :)